# Can I change caption of a figure from "Figure" to "Table"

Tags: tables, captions

The captions of the figures in latex start with Figure 1 or Figure 2.

However, I am inserting a table (which I have drawn using powerpoint).
I do not want the caption "Figure". Instead, I want the caption a Table (and that too over the figure.) can someone help me with that?

Please refer to the following figure for my table.

[image]

Comment: `\begin{table}\caption{my power-point table imported as image} \label{tab:my table} 
 \includegraphics{<table file name>}\end{table}`

Comment: however, this simple table can be easy set in `latex` ...

Comment: Thanks, if you post your comment in the answer, I can mark it as accepted. Meanwhile, I do know how to draw the table, but it gives a hard time in adjusting the formatting, like wrapped text etc.

Comment: now i have some spare time and convert my comment to the answer.

Comment: For heaven's sake, do not do that, neither in a figure nor in a table float. Importing tables as images is botched job because the type and size of the font will not fit anything with the rest of the document and also a text in PNG or JPG image could have a worse quality (will look pixelated unless you print it at more than 300 dots per inch).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

let me convert my comment to an answer ...

caption title is determined by type of float environment in which is your table:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{my power-point table imported as image} 
\label{tab:my table} 
\includegraphics{<table file name>}
\end{table}
```

this works in any document class and also without using any package dedicated for formatting of captions.

in the case, that you like to have your table outside of the `table` float environment, than you can use the package `caption` or `capt-of` (which is small part of the `caption` package) and define caption as

```
\captionof{table}{my power-point table imported as image}
```

regarding table, you will far better result by set it in `latex`. for example as show [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) in her/his answer or in case that you prefer have it more colorful (not recommended):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % for T1 font coding

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % for coloring table
\usepackage{array}          % for redefined "m" column type
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{My colorful table}
\label{tab:network-1}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.32}
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt}
    %\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \rowcolors{1}{blue!30}{blue!15}
\begin{tabular}{ C{0.33\linewidth}|C{0.3\linewidth}|C{0.3\linewidth} }
    \rowcolor{blue}
    & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Network Assisted}}
                            & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Autonomous}}    \\
    \hline
Operational domain
    & Under-coverage        & Under-coverage, out-of-coverage           \\
    \hline
Synchronization
    & Base-station assisted & Base-station assisted, autonomous         \\
    \hline
Collision/halfduplexing failures
    & None                  & Inevitable                                \\
    \hline
Time-to-discovery
    & Highly predictable    & Less predictable                          \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
see my nice table \ref{tab:network-1} \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `\captionof{table}{Captiontext}`

`\caption` is used in the table float, but figures and tables do not necessarily need to be in a float. When using `\captionof` the caption will be inserted and behaving the same as other captions.

I do recommend to convert your MS Office table to a LaTeX format. Tables as images don't magnify well on screen and the printing quality isn't as good.

This is a convenient macro VBA to convert the table from Excel. https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX

Answer (score 2):

Use the chance and create a much cleaner table in latex.

See https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf for a few design suggestions

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{heading}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}RRR@{}}
\toprule
& Network Assisted & Autonomous\\
\midrule
Operational domain & Under-coverage & Under-coverage, out-of-coverage\\ 
Synchronization & Base-station assisted & Base-station assisteeed, autonomous\\ 
Collision/half-duplexing failures & None & Inevitable\\ 
Time-to-discovery & Highly predictable & Less predictable\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]